# Python error: list index our of range, no value works

Tags: python

I am learning to use python for a class, so I am very new to the language. I am working on an exercise and I keep encountering an error that I can not find a solution for:

```
 File "get-weather-data.py", line 27, in <module>
    dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"})[1].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have changed the index number and nothing seems to work -here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Create/open file called wunder.txt
f = open('wunder-data.txt', 'w')

#Iternate though months and day 
for m in range (1, 13):
    for d in range (1, 32):

#Check if already gone through month 
if (m == 2 and d > 28):
    break
elif (m in [4, 6, 9, 11] and d > 30):
    break

# Open wunderground.com url
timestamp = '2009' + str(m) + str(d)
print "Getting data for " + timestamp
url = "http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBUF/2009/"
str(m) + "/" + str(d) + "/dailyhistory.html"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

# Get temperature from page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
# dayTemp 
    dayTemp = soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"}[1].get_text()

#Format month for timestamp
    if len(str(m)) < 2:
        mStamp = '0' + str(m)
    else:
        mStamp = str(m)

#Format day for timestamp
    if len(str(d)) < 2:
        dStamp = '0' +str(d)
    else:
        dStamp = str(d)

# Build Timestamp
    timestamp = '2009' + mStamp + dStamp 

#Write timestamp and temperature to file
    f.write(timestamp + ',' +dayTemp + '\n')

# Done 
f.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in this line:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"}[1].get_text()
```

specifically, `{"class":"wx-value"}[1]`. You can't expect the list to always come back with more than 1 item, you never know how many items you are going to get.

Instead you should look at the output returned from:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"wx-value"}.get_text()
```

and figure out how to parse it.

Comment: Thank you - that helped with the index error, but now I am getting this new error:

  File "get-weather-data.py", line 30
    if len(str(m)) < 2:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user3393036 please edit your code, it seems to me like your indentation might be off or you missed/added extra character some where.